# How to make Javascript in head load only after all elements has been loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload

This is a image slider. Basically taken from w3school.

```
<head>
<script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="slider">
        <img class="sliderImage" src="images/slider/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="sliderImage" src="images/slider/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="sliderImage" src="images/slider/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="sliderImage" src="images/slider/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <a id="sliderprev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"> &#10094; </a>
        <a id="slidernext" onclick="plusDivs(1)"> &#10095; </a>
    </section>
</body>
```

And the external js file:

```
var slideIndex=1;
sliderFunction(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(a){
    sliderFunction(slideIndex += a);
}

function sliderFunction(a){
    var i;
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderImage");
    if(a > b.length){
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if(a < 1){
        slideIndex = b.length;
    }
    for(i=0; i < b.length; i++){
        b[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    b[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

So it only works whenever I place `<script>` after those `<image>` and `<a>`. I know this that js file loads before document and that's causing the problem. How exactly do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it matter where JavaScript is placed on a html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308767/does-it-matter-where-javascript-is-placed-on-a-html-page)

Comment: Long story short, you don't want to put your JS in the `<head>` because it will block the page loading until the JS file is 100% loaded. Put it at the end of the `<body>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> So it only works whenever I place  after those `<image>` and `<a>`.

Which is [what you should do](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), barring a good reason to do something else. Put your `script` tags at the very end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. That way, all of the elements are available to the script code, and loading the scripts doesn't delay rendering the page.

If you *have* to put them elsewhere, use [`async` or `defer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) but beware of script loading order issues issues if you're using multiple scripts. (And check for proper support in your target browsers.)

If you can't do that, use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event; all modern browsers support it:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Code here
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)**.

> The **DOMContentLoaded** event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, **without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.**

Example :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var slideIndex=1;
    sliderFunction(slideIndex);
}, false);
```

Hope this helps.